# Can systemd-networkd handle interfaces in network namespace?

Tags: systemd, namespace, systemd-networkd, network-namespaces

I'm trying to configure systemd-networkd on an embedded system where wlan0 is in a separate network namespace.  I'd like for systemd to configure and monitor the interaface so that related services can start when the network becomes available.

If I leave wlan0 is in the default network namespace, then networkctl shows the network is up and routeable and everything works as expected.

```
# networkctl status wlan0
6: wlan0
             Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
          Network File: /etc/systemd/network/wlan.network
                  Type: wlan
                 State: routable (configured)
                  Path: platform-47810000.mmc
                Driver: brcmfmac
            HW Address: 00:25:ca:2e:f6:e5
                   MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 1500)
  Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/0
               Address: 192.168.101.1
```

I don't see any way to configure systed-netword to assign the interface to a different namespace.  If I manually move the wlan0/phy0 interface to a different namespace before systemd-networkd starts (using iw command in another systemd service), then systemd-networkd is unable to find the wlan0 interface.

```
Feb 16 16:01:34 buildroot systemd[1]: Starting Attach wlan0 to to network namespace inet_ns...
Feb 16 16:01:35 buildroot systemd[1]: Started Attach wlan0 to to network namespace inet_ns.
Feb 16 16:01:35 buildroot systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Feb 16 16:01:35 buildroot systemd-networkd[427]:
Feb 16 16:01:36 buildroot systemd-networkd[427]: Enumeration completed
Feb 16 16:01:36 buildroot systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Feb 16 16:01:36 buildroot systemd-networkd[427]: wlan0: Could not find device, waiting for device initialization: No such device
```

If I manually move the wlan0/phy0 interface to a different namespace after systemd-networkd starts, then networkd sees it, but later networkctl is unable to find the device:

```
# networkctl status wlan0
Failed to query link bit rates: Unknown object '/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_36'.
6: wlan0
             Link File: n/a
          Network File: n/a
                  Type: wlan
                 State: n/a (unmanaged)
            HW Address: 00:25:ca:2e:f6:e5
                   MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 1500)
  Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/0
```

What's the correct way to move an interface to a different network namespace under systemd?

Comment: Seems like maybe this is currently under development: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/14915